# Need to find all zip codes within a radius in miles from a specified zipcodes

Tags: java, android, computational-geometry, zipcode

I know how to get longitudes and longitudes from a zip code. 
I also have a database with multiple locations with their zip codes and coordinates.

I want to find the limits of a latitude and longitude based on the radius and then to match them up against possibilities in my database.

I read about the haversine?? formula. But, i don't understand it and looking for an explanation of how to find the limits of the latitude and longitudes.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Java as one of multiple google hits on "haversine java".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Haversine** is for geographic calculations, where the curving globe influences distances. Especially for short distances irrelevant.

Given an earth radius R:

```
Δ y = (ΔLatitude mod 360)  * 2π R / 360
```

But a Δ longitude gets 0 when reaching a pole (latitude = ±90).

```
Δ x = (ΔLongitude mod 360)  * 2π R * (90 - |avg latitude|) / 90 / 360
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

*(The underlined part should be something like `cos(avg latitude in radians)`  but SQL rarely provides a cosine function.)*

And hence

```
distance = √(Δx² + Δy²)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing for me, if you want to find the limits to a zip code as in with lat, long bounds that would be more appropriate or the lat, long bounds of a city or county or region -- this is a complicated problem and means creating structures in your database to represent all the points to create a polygon describing the bounds of a region.

Additionally, if you wanted to find the zip code of a lat, long value you could use Google's Geocoding API.  Which is a simple resource to query using an HTTP request
reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=nl

On the Haversine Formula, it is used to accurately describe a distance between two points on a curved space, if you are looking to interpret distances then you would need to use this formula (one example being distance between two map addresses you can then correlate to a lat,long value for each map address and then calculate the distance based on the radius of the curved space).

Good luck!

Comment: I want to find all possible locations with in a radius of my specified zipcode. For this i got a latitude and longitude with Geocoder. I figured best way to find if a location is within the radius is to see if it's latitude and longitude fall in that limit.

Comment: Zipcodes aren't circular naturally, they have polygon bounds so for instance, if you wanted to know if something was within some distance of a point that would make more sense versus some distance away from a zipcode (a region) would be just an expanded region to show any additional "radius" distance to keep within. The only purpose for haversine would be to convert a specified radius in meters and to DD (decimal degrees). If you have two points in lat,long you would just need to know that the third point is within your two by min,max values.You could try keeping radius in DD instead for ease.